# Creating range of numeric values based on array of strings

Tags: c#, array

Basically I have an array of strings. In this array, a range separator word might exist. For this example, I'm going to use the word `to` as range separator. We can assume that the range separator is not the first or last entry in the array. If we find the range separator we need to get the entry before and the entry after the separator, compare the two entries that we can assume are safe to parse as `integer` and find the character that differs between them. We then need to create new entries by counting up the number that is different, and return an `IEnumerable<string>` containing the new entries. We can also assume that only one character will differ between the start of the range and the end of the range.

For example, if the array contains these values:

```
1102
to
1602
```

we need to return

```
1202
1302
1402
1502
```

And here's my code:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetRangeSegments(string[] segments, string rangeIndicator)
{
    var rangeIndicatorIndex = Array.IndexOf(segments, rangeIndicator);
    var rangeSegments = new string[] { };

    if (rangeIndicatorIndex < 0)
    {
        return rangeSegments;
    }

    var rangeStart = segments[rangeIndicatorIndex - 1];
    var rangeEnd = segments[rangeIndicatorIndex + 1];

    var startChars = rangeStart.ToCharArray();
    var endChars = rangeEnd.ToCharArray();

    if (startChars.Length != endChars.Length)
    {
        return rangeSegments;
    }

    var diffIndex = -1;

    for (var i = 0; i < startChars.Length; i++)
    {
        if (startChars[i] == endChars[i])
        {
            continue;
        }

        diffIndex = i;
        break;
    }

    if (diffIndex == -1)
    {
        return rangeSegments;
    }

    var start = int.Parse(startChars[diffIndex].ToString()) + 1;
    var end = int.Parse(endChars[diffIndex].ToString());

    var numbers = Enumerable.Range(start, end - start);
    return rangeSegments.Concat(numbers.Select(number => rangeStart.Remove(diffIndex, 1).Insert(diffIndex, number.ToString())));
}
```

Comment: @Heslacher That shouldn't happen in my case, but if it does it should probably return an empty collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a method returns an `IEnumerable<T>` we expect an deffered execution using the `yield` keyword.

To make this happen and have a valid parameter validation we need another method which calls the method which is yielding.

So let us add one

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetRangeSegments(string[] segments, string rangeIndicator)
{
    if (segments==null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(segments)); }
    if (rangeIndicator == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rangeIndicator)); }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rangeIndicator)) { throw new ArgumentException("May not be empty.", nameof(rangeIndicator)); }

    return GetSegments(segments, rangeIndicator);
}
```

All the `if` statements will be executed and if the code comes to `return` it will immediately return because it knows about the `yield`ings in the `GetSegments()` method.

Using `yield` makes the empty `string[] rangeSegments` superflous because we just `yield break`. If you call `ToArray()` on the result of these `yield break` you get an empty array.

Because you can access the chars of a `string` by using its index you don't need `ToCharArray()`.

If there isn't by some mistake either `rangeStart[diffIndex]` or `rangeEnd[diffIndex]` a digit the code blows up at the call to `int.Parse()`. A better way would be to use `int.TryParse()` and if this doesn't succeed you could `yield break`.

But if we e.g do `int start = rangeStart[diffIndex] + 1;` then the ascii value of that char will be casted to an int which we then can check if `47 < start < 58` and if not we `yield break` here.

The return statmenet in your method is just unreadable, hence hard to maintain as well. To "replace" a single `char` inside a `string` we can just use a `StringBuilder`.

Summing all up lead to

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetRangeSegments(string[] segments, string rangeIndicator)
{
    if (segments == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(segments)); }
    if (rangeIndicator == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(rangeIndicator)); }
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rangeIndicator)) { throw new ArgumentException("May not be empty.", nameof(rangeIndicator)); }
    return GetSegments(segments, rangeIndicator);
}

private const int ascii0 = 48;
private const int ascii9 = 57;
private static IEnumerable<string> GetSegments(string[] segments, string rangeIndicator)
{
    var rangeIndicatorIndex = Array.IndexOf(segments, rangeIndicator);

    if (rangeIndicatorIndex < 0 || rangeIndicatorIndex == segments.Length - 1)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var rangeStart = segments[rangeIndicatorIndex - 1];
    var rangeEnd = segments[rangeIndicatorIndex + 1];

    if (rangeStart.Length != rangeEnd.Length)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var diffIndex = GetFirstDifferentCharPosition(rangeStart, rangeEnd);
    if (diffIndex == -1)
    {
        yield break;
    }

    var start = rangeStart[diffIndex] + 1;
    if (start < ascii0 || start > ascii9) { yield break; }

    var end = rangeEnd[diffIndex];
    if (end < ascii0 || end > ascii9) { yield break; }

    if (end < start) { yield break; }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(rangeStart);
    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        sb[diffIndex] = (char)i;
        yield return sb.ToString();
    }

}
private static int GetFirstDifferentCharPosition(string first, string second)
{
    var diffIndex = -1;

    for (var i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
    {
        if (first[i] != second[i])
        {
            diffIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return diffIndex;
}
```

Comment: I'm not going to upvote your answer this time because I bet it's about winning another hat, probably for not getting any votes ;-P

Comment: Thanks, great answer. One simple question, I realize it doesn't have any impact on functionality, but sometimes you write the `yield break` on the same line as the condition, and sometimes you don't. Are there any general guidelines for this? Or is it just when it looks nice to do it?

Comment: Just mixing styles, something one shouldn't do :-(

Comment: You should choose one style to use and stick to it. Here in the edit windows the `yield break;` would have to far on the right side so I placed it on a new line which I should have done for the others as well.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my implementation of this. I chose a simpler way to go about it:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        IEnumerable<string> retorno = GetInterval(new string[] { "1201", "to", "1601" }, "to");
        foreach(var item in retorno)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<string> GetInterval(string[] segments, string separator)
    {
        List<string> lReturn = new List<string>();
        int separatorIndex = Array.IndexOf(segments, separator);
        string first = segments[separatorIndex - 1];
        string second = segments[separatorIndex + 1];
        int indexDiffer = -1;
        bool isDifferent = false;

        while (!(isDifferent = first[indexDiffer] != second[indexDiffer])) { indexDiffer++; };

        if (!isDifferent)
            return null;

        var counter = Convert.ToInt32(first.Remove(indexDiffer + 1)) + 1;
        var endRange = Convert.ToInt32(second.Remove(indexDiffer + 1));

        for (; counter < endRange; counter++)
            lReturn.Add(string.Concat(counter, first.Substring(indexDiffer + 1)));

        return lReturn;
    }
```

In my implementation i try to not use Linq, it will probably give you a better performance because you are controlling the iterations, also it gives you better maintenance.

Comment: Please describe your changes. Pure code dumps are off-topic and may be deleted.

Comment: Hope it is better now, thank  you @t3chb0t